# How to set value in a cell using QtActive

Tags: c++, windows, excel, qt, qaxobject

i am trying to put the values into an excel sheet through QtActive's QAxObject. i succeeded upto getting a work sheet. Now the win32 API to set the value for a cell is

```
Some_Excel_Object xx=worksheet->Cells();
xx->item[row][column] = 5;
```

Here i got upto the "xx". But,I don't know how to implement the above second line. I will be very thankful to the person who sheds a light on this issue.

Comment: Your post seems to receive little attention, have your already fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

In Qt we can do it by using following piece of code.

```
int rowRange = 1;
int colRange = 1;
QString values = "Test";
QAxObject * range = temp_Worksheet->querySubObject("Cells(int,int)",rowRange,colRange);
range->setProperty("Value",values);
```

Try this !!
Good Luck !!